# How can I use vim to substitute all whole lines that match a Regex

Tags: regex, vim, replace, tex

There I have a tex file which contains serval paragraphs like:

```
\paragraph{name1}

...

\paragraph{name2}

...
```

Now I want to substitute all the "paragraph" with item, just like:

```
\item
...

\item
...
```

to reach that I have tried many commands and finally i used this:
(note that I used "a:" to "z:" as paragraph names)

```
**:% s/\\paragraph[{][a-z]:[}]/\\item/g**
```

and I think that is nether pretty nor efficient. I have tried to match the line contains "paragraph" but somehow only this word is replaced. Now that I can delete all such lines with

```
**:% g/_*paragraph_*/d**
```

are there anyway better to perform a substitute in the same way?(or to say to substitute all the line contains a specific word)

Comment: So `\paragraph{<anything here>}` would get replaced with only `\item`? Your expected output is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Are you okay with macros? They do the same job, without use of complex regex.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Exactly, what I want is like: replace all the line contains "paragraph" with \item(that's the whole line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to do with `macro`!
First, search the pattern using `/` like `/\paragraph`

Let's start the macro. Clear register `a` by pressing `qaq`.
Press `qa` to start recording in register `a`.
Press `n` to go its occurence. Then, press `c$` to delete till end of line and to insert the text. Then, type the text and then press `escape` key.

Press `@a` to repeat the process. End macro by pressing `q`.

Now, macro is recorded and you can press `@a` once to make changes in all such lines.

Comment: It's a good idea, I haven't thought that way. But I think maybe it still takes a lot of time if there are more than 50 of such lines?

Comment: It takes a second or two. You should execute macros , you will fall in love with them ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was almost correct. Rather than this

```
:% s/\paragraph[{][a-z]:[}]/\item/g
```

Use this

```
:% s/^\\paragraph{[a-z|0-9]\+}$/\\item/g
```

**Let's break it down piece by piece:**

1. The `^` character matches the start of the line, so that you don't match something like this:

   `Some text \paragraph{abc}`
2. The reason why we use `\\` instead of `\` is because `\` is an escape character, so to match it, we escape the escape character.
3. Doing `[a-z|0-9]\+` will match one or more a-z or 0-9 characters, which is what I assume your paragraph names are composed of. If you need capital letters, you could do something like `[a-zA-Z|0-9]\+`.
4. Finally, we anchor the expression to the end of the line with `$`, so that it does not match lines that don't fit this pattern exactly.

Comment: `[a-z|0-9]` is the same as `[a-z0-9|]`: it matches a lowercase letter or a digit or `|`.

Comment: If your regex is anchored like that, `/g` makes no difference.

Comment: It do works in that case, thanks. But my question is, if I haven't asked clearly, how to replace a longer and more complex line which contains a specific word such as "paragraph" here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
:%s/\\paragraph{[^{}]*}/\\item/g
```

This finds all occurrences of `\paragraph{`, followed by 0 or more non-`{}` characters, followed by `}` (i.e. something like `\paragraph{stuff here}`), and replaces them by `\item`.

---

Or if you want to replace all lines containing `paragraph`:

```
:%s/^.*paragraph.*$/\\item/
```

Comment: It works and better than mine. But still, I want to find out how to describe a complex line in a short way.